# Prestashop - Auto logout after successfull login

Tags: php, session, cookies, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Some of prestashop users have a problem with front office login. in some sites users cannot login (logout immediately without any error), in some sites successful login done but when you refresh the page, you will logout. In some sites you will logout after adding a product to cart. Please notice that just some customers have this problem.

I checked core's php codes deeply and i think there is not any bug in prestashop code because when I moved a site to another server, or when I use cloudflare.com cdn servers the problem solved!

I think that the problem happen when cookies are sent to browser because there are id_customer and logged flag in Context->cookie of prestashop even after the initfooter() ended!

Please help me to know what configuration in php.ini or server can cause the problem (Like session , cookie, suhosin or others).

How can I simulate what cloudflare.com do to controll or compress cookie in my site?

Edit: I found that litespeed web server can affect prestashop cookie

Answer (score 0):

### Prestashop v 1.5.6.2

/classes/Cookie.php

Try **comment** this lines lines 290 and 291 or so..:

```
/* Check if cookie has not been modified */
// if (!isset($this->_content['checksum']) || $this->_content['checksum'] != $checksum)
// $this->logout();
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

For Prestashop version >= 1.4.7 you can login to Prestashop admin, click on Preference, set “Check IP on the cookie” to “No”

[Credit & details](https://www.vodien.com/knowledge-base/articles/prestashop-issue)